# React handle form submit after being redirected by server (with data )?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, frontend

React front-end submits a form (POST) which is sent to the backend. This server then responds with a js object which contains html (I thought it was supposed to redirect)?

How am I supposed to redirect the user to the page that was received?

For example if I `curl -X POST api.example.com` the api, it returns pure html like this:

`<html>
...
</html>`

When using postman, it automatically renders this html. How am I supposed to deal with this in React?

Comment: Why you need to send complete html from backend? Just return the ur from backend and redirect it on frontend using `location.href`

Comment: Can you check on `react-router-dom`s `redirect` or `history` package.

Comment: @YousafHassan unfortunately we don't control the server, neither are we able to get them to change what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

If you use NodeJS + express

Example:

```
http.get('*',function(req,res){  
    res.redirect('/'+req.url);
})
```

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to specific page using react-router.

```
Step 1: Wrap your <App /> inside <BrowserRouter />
```

Go to you component where service is called and then redirect user after receiving service response.

```
this.route.navigate(['/']);
```

As you are saying your receiving HTML in response of REST service call. If you want to render this content on page.

```
let content = null;

content = response.data; // assign data to variable
```

Now display this in component like this:

```
class Content extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
     {this.content}
     ); 
    }
 }
```